# Getting the Total of Discounted Amount on DataGridView BUG

Tags: vb.net

The process is that when you select rows from this DGV to other DGV, the other DGV should get the total of discounted amount and output on a Label. But somehow it has a bug. Instead of compute the total it just displays the first cell.

Code:

```
Private Sub Checkout_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim amount As Double = 0
    For i = 0 To DGV_Checkout.Rows.Count - 1
        amount += DGV_Checkout.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
    Next
    lblTotal.Text = amount
End Sub
```

Comment: When you debugged the code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code, how and where did what you actually saw differ from what you expected to see?

Comment: `Option Strict On`

Comment: You're running that code in the Load event of a Winform (assumed Winform, due to the DataGridView). Is the DataGridView even loaded at this point? Why are you handling MyBase.Load? Are you using Form inheritance?

Comment: I basically just figured out that I have to use the button from the previous Window Form. I'd thought it would work because on my previous work it did work on coding it on the Load Event.